# Selecting a XElement from a XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I really didn't want to ask for help as I know I'll eventually figure it out, but I've spent too much time, if the document had parent tags or a better structure, it would be a piece of cake. Sadly I'm downloading the document, and I just can't figure out how to get the data.

I've tried a a few linq queries and a foreach using XElement as an iterator. Anyway here's an example of the structure.

```
<ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:yahoo:srch" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:srch http://api.search.yahoo.com/SiteExplorerService/V1/InlinkDataResponse.xsd" totalResultsAvailable="247930100" firstResultPosition="99" totalResultsReturned="100">
 <Result>
  <Title>Adobe - Adobe Reader</Title> 
  <Url>http://get.adobe.com/fr/reader/</Url> 
  <ClickUrl>http://get.adobe.com/fr/reader/</ClickUrl> 
  </Result>
 <Result>
  <Title>Religious Tolerance</Title> 
  <Url>http://www.religioustolerance.org/</Url> 
  <ClickUrl>http://www.religioustolerance.org/</ClickUrl> 
  </Result>
 <Result>
  <Title>Applications Internet riches (RIA) | Adobe Flash Player</Title> 
  <Url>http://www.adobe.com/fr/products/flashplayer/</Url> 
  <ClickUrl>http://www.adobe.com/fr/products/flashplayer/</ClickUrl> 
  </Result>
 <Result>
  <Title>photo management software | Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3</Title> 
  <Url>http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/</Url> 
  <ClickUrl>http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/</ClickUrl> 
  </Result>
 <Result>
  <Title>Battle for Wesnoth</Title> 
  <Url>http://www.wesnoth.org/</Url> 
  <ClickUrl>http://www.wesnoth.org/</ClickUrl> 
  </Result>
</ResultSet>
```

Here's an example of a latest snippet.

```
foreach (XElement ele in xDoc.Descendants("ResultSet").Elements("Result"))
                {
                    CollectedUris.Add(ele.Element("Url").Value);
                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to add an `XNamespace`:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:yahoo:srch";

var query = xDoc.Root.Descendants( ns + "Result" ).Elements( ns + "Url" )

foreach( XElement e in query )
{
    CollectedUris.Add( e.Value );
}
```

**Edit**:
A LINQ solution for bonus points:

```
xDoc.Root.Descendants( ns + "Result" )
    .Elements( ns + "Url" )
    .Select( x => x.Value ).ToList()
    .ForEach( CollectedUris.Add );
```

Comment: Ah I had no idea it about namespaces, certainly wouldn't have solved it without someones help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want **all** `<Url>` elements in the document.  If that's the case, then your loop is almost there.  You will want to do the following.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

foreach (XElement ele in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Result").Descendants("Url")
{
    CollectedUris.Add(ele.Value);
}
```

`Root` gets you a reference to the root element, and the following `Descendants` statement returns only the `<Result>` nodes.  The last `Descendants` statement further constrains the `<Result>` node enumerator to only return `<Url>` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I've updated the xml structure as it wasn't readable. Anyway weirdly the Add method within the loop isn't fired (got a break point on it) Could you check out the structure and make sure I'm not doing something dumb. Thanks again

Comment: @Ash - see my solution. Steve's is correct if there is not a namespace, but your example requires a namespace manager.